# If else conditions in python

Tags: python, pandas

I want check string in Columns[0] and if we have & symbol in the column[0] string then need to return columns[1] value otherwise return columns[0] string on that row.
i tried to use below login but is not returning expected result
X = dataframe

```
x.iloc[:,0]
x.iloc[:,1]
for i in :
    if (x.iloc[i,0].str.contains(pat ='&')).all() == 'TRUE':
        print(x.iloc[i,1])
    else:
        print(x.iloc[i,0])
```

Below is the sample dataframe columns

```
NE Name                 Subrack
ABC                      master
Site1&site2              site1
site3&site4              site3
site5                    master
site6&site8              site6
```

thanks

Comment: There are several problems in your code: What's `x`? There's something missing in your `for` clause. The indentation is off.

Comment: This is not even valid code. [ask] [mre]

Comment: i am really new to python and this you can say my first few code , please possible can you guide me with code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you are using pandas library, as so please avoid `for-loop` iteration.
regarding your question, here is a valid code:

```
x.loc[x['NE Name'].str.contains('&'), 'Subrack']
```